# If $f$ is Lipschitz of order $1$ over $[a,b]$, is it true that $f$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, lipschitz-functions

> If $f$ is Lipschitz of order $1$ over $[a,b]$, is it true that $f$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$?

We are given that there is a constant $C$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $[a,b]$. I think there should be a counterexample to this since we can easily show a counterexample if our domain is $(-\infty,\infty)$. I think the same should be true here.

Comment: $|x-c|$ for some $c\in (a, b)$?

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = |x|$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Are you saying that $||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Yes. You can see it by, for example, taking square on both sides.

Comment: @Puzzled417 That's called the reverse triangle inequality.